# C++ save pointer members with class when writing to file

Tags: c++, pointers, std

I have a simple binary tree implementation in C++. I'm saving it to a file via `std::ofstream::write((char*)&myTree, sizeof(mytree));`.

However, the class is defined with pointers for the left and right nodes because of incomplete types.

```cpp
class Node
{
public:
    int value;
    Node(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

How do I dereference the pointers and save the left and right nodes with the root node in the tree?

Comment: For serialization you might use some JSON or XML file structure, these allow to save tree like structures in a very natural way.

Comment: `std::ofstream::write((char*)&myTree, sizeof(mytree));.` you certainly can't do that. You will be saving meaningless pointers. You may want to read here: [https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers refer to a specific location in memory.  They can't be persisted to disk.  When you start a new process and read them back, your process's memory layout will be different.  So, what you're doing will not work.

You're going to have to write a custom serializer for your class, to handle its structure.

boost::serialization is a decent place to start: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

There's also cereal: https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/

As another commenter pointed out, this is a handy summary of the state of serialization in C++: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization